# Setting the size of a Flask wtforms Textarea based on surrounding divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a UI where two versions of a text is shown side-by-side, and the user can edit the text on the right using a wtform textarea.

```
    <div class="row-fluid" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-top:20px; padding-right:20px; border-right: 1px solid #ccc;">
            <p><b>元の文章</b></p>
            {% for sentence in sentences %}
                {% for word in sentence %}
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="popover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" title="{{ word.0 }}&#013;{{ word.1 }}">{{ word.0 }}</a>
                {% endfor %}
                <br><br>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-top:20px;">
            <form class="form" method="post" role="form">
                {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                {{ wtf.form_errors(form, hiddens="only") }}
                {{ wtf.form_field(form.edited_text, rows='1000') }}
                {{ wtf.form_field(form.submit) }}
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am trying to set the `rows` parameter of the textarea to be equal of the length of the column div on the left. Is this possible?

Thanks!

EDIT

I came up with a hacky solution using jQuery:

```
<script>
        window.onload = function() {
            if (window.jQuery) {
                var height = $("#originalText").height();
                $(".form-group").height(height);
                $("#edited_text").height(height-40);
            }
        };
</script>
```

I added ID: originalText to the first div, and then proceeded to edit the height parameters of the form containers with the value.